# LOAD DATA INFILE in phpMyAdmin 4.2.10.1 don’t work #7890

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, load-data-infile

***i'm really disappointed that only one person have some idea how to solve my problem!!!***

I already have try to find thoroughly (2 hours!) the answer in all the other discussion, but nothing compare to my challenge!

I work with a hosted phpmyadmin installation with Win 10 and I try to load a file in a table.

When I start the import function of phpmyadmin, the sql-script will be found and started, but I get allways the

error #7890 – can’t find file ‘D:\Loader\doshas.txt’.

'load.sql':
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE “D:\Loader\doshas.txt” INTO TABLE doshas terminated by ‘,’;

The file 'load.sql' is  in the same folder as doshas.txt! 
What’s wrong?

Regards and thanks

Comment: Does `doshas.txt` exist locally or on the server?  I.e. is this file where you are executing `LOAD DATA` or is it on the server?

Comment: It sounds to me like `doshas.txt` is on the server, in which case you should be using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, without `LOCAL`.

Comment: Hi Tim, i already try all the possible combinations... to copy doshas.txt into /wwwroot on the server and without local... should

Comment: ...should i have another folder on the server?

Comment: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE “D:\\Loader\\doshas.txt”` ..m what are those funky quotes around the file name?  Use single quotes.

Comment: ...that was one of my combinations! ;-) Doesn't work too!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't specified special characters.

I believe better way is to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.
Let's say you want to load the file doshas.txt to my_table with columns col_a, col_b, col_c.

Put the txt file in the path of mysql of phpadmin ex.For XAMPP is xamp\mysql\data

Then in phpmyadmin -> code SQL write

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'doshas.txt' INTO TABLE `my_table` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(col_a, col_b, col_c);
```